# when I search unanswered sometimes I found with answer

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions, question-lists

When I search unanswered sometimes I found with answer

For example I search https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered

and found 1 answer for:
[Error Could not find or load main class (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44482356/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-java)

I expect to find question with no answer at all

Comment: "Unanswered" means as far as I remember: no Answer or no answer accepted yet. Funny though, then I use your first link, then I also get questions with accepted answers.

Comment: that's the bug, no?

Comment: @user7294900 you tell us; do you mean found with *accepted* answer? Note that those questions with accepted answers that appear in *"need-answers"* also have open bounties, so perhaps that's taken into account.

Comment: I thought unanswered  = 0 answers. and the returned questions has no bounty

Comment: Note the URL is redirected to `need-answers`, not just `unanswered`, and as for *"the returned questions has no bounty"* literally the first question I see in that list does: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9452701/3001761. The example you post does not have any upvoted or accepted answer, so it seems like the OP's problem isn't yet solved and further answers may be required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, "unanswered" doesn't mean that there are no answers, but that there is no accepted answer. For example, the question you linked to has no accepted answer. If you want questions with no answers, you can go to the [no answers tab](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers).

Answer (score 3):

Theres answers but the question havent accept any yet, thats why its still unanswered.